# JSlider resize for high resolution screens

Tags: java, swing, resolution, jslider

I have a laptop with a new and high resolution screen (3840 x 2160) and I am trying to implement a Java Swing interface with a JSlider control.  The problem is, the control part of the slider does not seem to scale with the screen resolution and so appears to be microscopic.  Not the width of the whole slider *bar*, which is trivially settable, just the control part that a user will have to grab hold of with a mouse interface.  Using this slider is an exercise in frustration.

Changing the screen resolution during use is not a desired solution.  (And doesn't seem to work, anyway.)

If `slider.putClientProperty("JComponent.sizeVariant", "large");` is doing anything useful, it is beyond my eyes' ability to perceive.

Is there a way to change the size of this interface?

Comment: ["Might" be of some help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659044/how-to-set-the-dpi-of-java-swing-apps-on-windows-linux)

Comment: @MadProgrammer more work than I was hoping for, but potentially useful.  Thanks.

Comment: In the interim, `JSlider` has useable focus & key bindings.

Comment: @trashgod I have a hard requirement for swift adjustments on a large and a small scale.  I'll be using key bindings (and buttons) for the latter, but I cannot sacrifice the former.  I'm willing to look at other Swing elements I may have overlooked, but I cannot have someone clicking madly to get from one side of the slider to the other.

Comment: You could try changing `thumbRect` in the `SliderUI` seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6996263/230513).