# New Computer, Resolution Problems with Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, jframe, resolution

So I recently just bought a new computer and it has 4k resolution. I am a student working with Eclipse IDE and cannot figure out a way to change the resolution in my preferences.  Specifically, I am working on a project for school that uses a JFrame, JTextFields, Graphics and the like. When the frame opens it is so small on my screen that I can't even see what I have created. The rest of my eclipse is perfectly sized. Is there a way to scale the resolution settings in Eclipse? To be clear...I do not want to change the resolution on anything else except for the frame and its contents. I am a beginner learning in Java and I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: What OS are you working on, and what version of Eclipse are you using? Older versions of Eclipse wouldn't properly scale on 4k displays, as far as I know, newer versions like Oxygen (4.7) and Photon (4.8) should work fine out of the box.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45426996/6505250 (Eclipse uses SWT as UI toolkit whereas `JFrame`, etc. is Java Swing).

Comment: @BrianFernandes I am using the latest version, photon from june 2018.

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1007783/258320) might help.

Comment: thank yoou so much1