# How can I display my Java (Swing GUI) application with a higher pixel density?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, graphics2d

My application is showing up quite pixelated / blurry, as if I didn't have a retina (High PPI) display. How can I increase the pixel density of the canvas so that everything looks sharp?

**Operating System:** macOS Mojave 10.14.4 **Java:** "12" 2019-03-19

I have tried transforming, scaling, rendering hints etc.. but I can't seem to get any higher pixel density.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SimpleCanvas
{
    private JFrame     frame;
    private CanvasPane canvas;
    private Graphics2D graphic;
    private Image      canvasImage;

    /**
     * Creates and displays a SimpleCanvas of the specified size and background 
     */
    public SimpleCanvas(String title, int width, int height, Color bgColour) {
        frame = new JFrame();
        canvas = new CanvasPane();
        frame.setContentPane(canvas);
        frame.setTitle(title);
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
        frame.pack();
        Dimension size = canvas.getSize();
        canvasImage = canvas.createImage(size.width,size.height);
        graphic = (Graphics2D) canvasImage.getGraphics();
        graphic.setColor(bgColour);
        graphic.fillRect(0,0,size.width,size.height);
        graphic.setColor(Color.black);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // higher quality rendering
        graphic.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graphic.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graphic.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
        graphic.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
        graphic.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
        graphic.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
        graphic.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        graphic.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
    }

    /** 
     * Draws a disc on this SimpleCanvas centred at x,y with radius r with colour c.
     */
    public void drawDisc(int x, int y, int r, Color c) {
        int d = r*2;
        setForegroundColour(c);
        graphic.fillOval(x - r, y - r, d, d); 
    }

    class CanvasPane extends JPanel {
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(canvasImage,0,0,null);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you just displaying an image? What is the pixel density of that?

Comment: No images. Just drawing circles with `graphic.fillOval(x, y, width, height);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the sad answer is: not possible.

When you check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659044/how-to-set-the-dpi-of-java-swing-apps-on-windows-linux) from 2013, you will find that people did not find a way to "force" higher DPI onto their swing applications.

And to my knowledge, nothing changed about that.

The really sad answer is that Java isn't a good language for creating a really great "modern" user experience, at least regarding "fat" desktop GUI clients. And as you can see on that other answer, Java9 promised to do better, but it seems: it doesn't.

If at all, the *answer* might be to go try JavaFX. Which is a problem by itself, as correctly bundling a JavaFX app can turn into a problem of its own.